# Union column values group by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataset.

```
colA ColB ColC
a      1   aa
a      1   Nan
a      2
a      2    bb
a      2    cc
```

I want an output as following

```
colA ColB ColC
a      1   aa
a      2   bb#cc
```

I am trying to group by ColA and ColB and union ColC values. I tried using following code in Pandas. but I didn't get

```
test1 = test(['colA','colB'])['colC'].apply(lambda x: x.sum() )
```

It has to avoid Nan or whitespaces in column and join all values with # seperator.

Answer (score 1):

1st `replace` all Nan and blank to `np.nan`, then `dropna`, and the problem just become simple `groupby` `agg` `join`

```
df=df.replace({'Nan':np.nan,' ':np.nan})
df.dropna().groupby(['colA','ColB'],as_index=False).ColC.agg(','.join)
  colA  ColB   ColC
0    a     1     aa
1    a     2  bb,cc
```